# Mobiscroll formato fecha

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy usando la librería **Mobiscroll** con jQuery y lo tengo todo por idiomas y formatos de fecha, mi duda es, cómo puedo hacer para que ese formato de fecha solo sea a nivel visual (según el idioma) y a la hora de mandarlo por POST se mande en un formato concreto que yo le indique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se debe utilizar un input hidden en el cual se le va a pasar el valor de la selección con el formato requerido.

```
<input id="myrange" />
<input id="myrange-start" type="hidden" />
<input id="myrange-end" type="hidden" />
```

JS:

```
$('#myrange').mobiscroll().range({
    onSet: function (event, inst) {
        var values = inst.getVal();
        $('#myrange-start').val(mobiscroll.util.datetime.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', values[0]);
        $('#myrange-end').val(mobiscroll.util.datetime.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', values[1]);
    }
});
```

Nota: Si estas usando 2.x, hay algunas pequeñas diferencias:

```
$('#myrange').mobiscroll().range({
    onSelect: function (valueText, inst) {
        var values = inst.getVal();
        $('#myrange-start').val($.mobiscroll.datetime.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', values[0]);
        $('#myrange-end').val($.mobiscroll.datetime.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', values[1]);
    }
});
```